# Does order of includes and declarations matter in C?

Tags: c

Are these equivalent? If not, which are equal and which are different?

**Case 1**

```
#include "file1.c"
#include "file2.c"

int test(int i); /* declaration */

int test(int i) {
    /* do something */
}
```

**Case 2**

```
#include "file2.c" 
#include "file1.c"

int test(int i); /* declaration */

int test(int i) {
    /* do something */
}
```

**Case 3**

```
int test(int i); /* declaration */

int test(int i) {
    /* do something */
}

#include "file1.c"
#include "file2.c"
```

**Case 4**

```
#include "file1.c"
#include "file2.c"

int test(int i) {
    /* do something */
}

int test(int i); /* declaration */
```

Case 1 and 2 asks if order of includes matter with each other. Case 3 asks if order of includes matter with non-include code. Case 4 asks if order of declaration matters.

Comment: Why would anyone in their right mind include a ```.c``` file instead of a ```.h```?

Comment: Well, these cases shouldn't be terribly difficult to test. This question might be better if it was asked as "Why does order matter in these cases but not these other cases?" after testing the cases.

Comment: @Cygwinnian -  A person who is learning C, can _at the same time_ include a .c, and be in their right mind.  That is why Stackoverflow is so popular with new programmers, or people learning a new language.

Comment: No i't not equivalent, and depending on the contents of file1.c and file2.c it might even not compile if you reverse the order. If file1.c contains declairations needed in file2.c then file1.c must be included before file2.c

Comment: Well I suppose you can imagine the .c files being standard libraries instead. They would both be a collection of functions, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something in `file1.c` uses something in `file2.c`, then case 1 will (probably) fail while case 2 succeeds. (I say probably because we don't know what's in `file1.c`.)

If the `do something` uses something in `file1.c` or `file2.c`, then case 3 will fail.

In case 4, the declaration is completely redundant. (It's redundant in case 3 too, unless there's something calling `test` between the declaration and the definition.)

Comment: So #include basically dumps the contents of the file at the position of #include? And declarations are only necessary when the function is used before it is defined?

Comment: @GeorgeNewton: 1) Yes, exactly, and 2) pretty much, but you also have varibles, templates and structs/classes to consider.

Answer (score 2):

For cases 1, 2 and 3 it depends. The C preprocessor simply replaces the file at the position where it is included. So it hugely depends on the contents of the files.

For case 4, it does not matter as long as the called function is written above the calling function.